# Android Google Map API 11

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to use satelite view and street view in my addLocation Activity..which method Should I call for satelite view and street view...`

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //    AddLocationActivity.this.mapView.setSatellite(false);
          //  AddLocationActivity.this.mapView.setStreetView(true);
            AddLocationActivity.this.mapView.invalidate();
            AddLocationActivity.this.streetText.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            AddLocationActivity.this.satelliteText.setBackgroundColor(-1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the version of your google maps api?

Comment: google maps api 11

Comment: the version... right now google maps has version 1 which is deprecated and version 2 and version 3

Comment: now what should i do?

Comment: what is the version of the google maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this part.

```
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

With this.

```
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

This will show satellite view.

Answer (score 1):

If you have added a map to your application or added a `MapFragment`, setting the initial state of the map can be done by configuring it with passing `GoogleMapOptions` object with your options specified.
You can create a GoogleMapOptions object like this:

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
```

And then configure it as follows:

```
options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE)
    .compassEnabled(false)
    .rotateGesturesEnabled(false)
    .tiltGesturesEnabled(false);
```

To know more about applying these options when creating a map, please check [Configure initial state - Programmatically](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#programmatically).